# How to use lightGallery with React.js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, lightgallery

I am trying to integrate [lightgallery plugin](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery) in my own project. But i can't using it in React controller.

My actions:
1) installing with npm

```
npm install lightgallery lg-thumbnail lg-autoplay lg-video lg-fullscreen lg-pager lg-zoom lg-hash lg-share --save-dev
```

2) import plugin into controller:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import HomeDom from './Home'
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'lightgallery';

export default class HomeClass extends Component {
render() {
    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
    return (
        <HomeDom />
    )
}
}
```

View component `HomeDom`:

```
import React from 'react'

const HomeDom = () => (
    <div className="home-main-wrapper">
        <div className="catalog-body">
            <div id="lightgallery">
                <a href="src">
                    <img alt="thumbnail" />
                </a>
                <a href="src">
                    <img alt="thumbnail" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default HomeDom
```

I get nothing with this configuration. Somebody solve this problem? Or there is a more friendly gallery plugin like lightgallery with its features (fullscreen, zoom, mobile device friendly and so on...).

Comment: don't forget to include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.8/css/lightgallery.min.css">` to your template html page. Without this css file plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you call your jQuery initializer the component has not been rendered yet and therefore the DOM element you are trying to select does not exist. [You should use refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to wait for your lightgallery container to render and only then initialize it:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import HomeDom from './Home'
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'lightgallery';

export default class Home extends Component {
    onLightGallery = node => {
        this.lightGallery = node;
        $(node).lightGallery();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        $(this.lightGallery).data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="home-main-wrapper">
                <div className="catalog-body">
                    <div id="lightgallery" ref={this.onLightGallery}>
                        <a href="src">
                            <img alt="thumbnail" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="src">
                            <img alt="thumbnail" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Also note that you should destroy the lightgallery when your component unmounts to remove unneeded event handlers.

Comment: @Halkyon Glad i could help. I saw i had the call to the jQuery initializer still in the render method. That was just a copy and paste mistake. You will not need it there anymore.

Comment: Hey @trixn, could you please check this question out? It is similar, but without using jquery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098790/react-lightgallery-js-integration-without-jquery